# Add Google IOT Device to Google Home as Device

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-home, google-cloud-iot

I read around 9 tutorials and 6 similar SO topics similar to what I ask, but none were conclusive or actually depicted what I need. So here goes.

I have a raspberry pi setup with a DTH22 sensor to send data to google iot cloud on pub/sub. Data is coming, all good.

Now, the end result here is to make a routine on google home that reads the sensor data (basically temperature) and issue a command to an added AC, based on temperature.

How do I add that sensor data as a device to google home to create that routine? Or is there another way to achieve this and I am coming at this completely wrong?

This is the first time I'm trying this so be kind. Ask anything, if I can, I will answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well nothing was found. So I ended up using Assistant Relay on the Raspberry Pi, which uses a node server to catch and transmit text based commands to google assistant (linked to the same account of the google home). In the script where I check the temperature and humidity from the DHT22 sensor I just added a few more lines to send commands to the local node server to turn on / off the ac, just as I would do via voice commands on my phone.

https://github.com/greghesp/assistant-relay